# CoreData Collection Server Sync

Tags: ios, core-data, synchronization

I need to sync my entities created on the client and saved in CoreData to my server. The server creates a GUID for the entity, persists it and sends it back to the client including the GUID. My problem is that my entity has a collection of other entities as an attribute (a one-to-many relationship) and when syncing I can’t properly match the GUID of the collections entities to my set of entities. The reason for that might be a different order in the collection or same titles.

I see two possibilities to solve this problem:

1. Basically replace the collection by emptying it when the response arrives and importing the new set of entities along with the GUIDs (what seems strange to me because I would have to do this even in an update scenario, always deleting the affected objects).
2. Send a client_id of the entities to the server, make the server save it and send it back in the response so I can match the entities in the collection.

Any advice?

Comment: Why not generate a GUID on client side for newly created items - that way you could connect your elements directly. Because it's a GUID, it'll be unique regardless of who creates it.

Comment: Personally I would never create IDs on the client out of security reasons. Also you would need to build some sort of collision detection on the server if malicious IDs were to be passed.